# From wavelets to curvelets

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, curves, approximation-theory

I've read that the curvelet is a generalisation of wavelet.

I am now looking for references such as books, lecture note or research papers introducing the mathematical theoretic aspect of curvelet to grasp it properly then I go further to see its applications.

Comment: This site might be a good start: http://www.curvelet.org/

Comment: ditto: https://www.google.com/search?q=curvelets